# porting from mac to linux/windows and looking for a cross platform XPC equivalent

Tags: xpc, nsxpcconnection

I'm using XPC and want to port to linux/windows.
Looking for an alternative which can perform similar functionality.

is there something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [gRPC](https://grpc.io) and probably [gRPC-Swift](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift). The Swift implementation is in alpha status, though. gRPC and Objective C cannot spawn a server, it can only be used as client. The swift implementation can. C++ can, too.

Comment: this is very far from what i am looking for. GRPC has no fascilities for launching services , connecting to services, etc.

Comment: Maybe you should use XPC on Mac and gRPC on linux/windows? I doubt you find something else similar - we searched the internet without success :(

Comment: Neither XPC nor GCD are really ported. I have come up with my own implementation.

Comment: @lothar libdispatch exists on Linux it’s in apples open source repo for swift on GitHub.  But xpc is not open for some reason.

Comment: @greg.casamento  GCD is not really ported because the Kernel is lacking necessary features that are non portable. It once was, but now Apple is using undocumented code to spawn threads from the kernel because only the kernels knows the real utilizatiion. I think Windows does the same with their threadpools. Unfortunately Linux is way too conservative and again 10 years behind with this.